# How to loop list object and getting it's element by index?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to migrate a function from java 7 to java8 but i'm stucked over getting the value of the indexed element while looping a list. What is the good way to do this ?

here is the code that i'm trying to migrate:

```
List<Employe> listEmploye = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i< ids.size();i++)
{
  Long idLong = Long.valueOf(ids.get(i));
  BigDecimal idBig= BigDecimal.valueOf(idLong);
  listEmploye.add(findByIdPointage(idBig));
}
```

Comment: What type is ids collection?

Comment: the type of ids list is **String**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 List<Employe> listEmploye = ids.stream()
          .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
          .mapToObj(BigDecimal::valueOf)
          .map(this::findByIdPointage)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Well there is a `BigDecimal` constructor that takes a `String`, thus this can be simplified to :

```
List<Employe> listEmploye = ids.stream()
           .map(BigDecimal::new) 
           .map(this::findByIdPointage)
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use Stream API to map your collection:

```
List<Employe> listEmploye  = ids.stream()
.map(Long::valueOf)
.map(BigDecimal::valueOf)
.map(this::findByIdPointage)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this approach would be very slow with larger data collections. This code should never see the production. You should first find all identifiers:

```
Set<BigDecimal> employeIdentifiers  = ids.stream()
.map(Long::valueOf)
.map(BigDecimal::valueOf)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then use a single repository call to fetch them all at once:

```
List<Employe> listEmploye = findByIdPointageIn(employeIdentifiers);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees(Set<String> ids) {
    return ids.stream()
              .map(id -> BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.parseLong(id)))
              .map(this::findByIdPointage)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your current approach, just because Java 8 introduce lambdas and new methods it doesn't mean you must use them.

If you want ti use streams you can do below. `Long.valueOf()` mapping is potentially redundant:

```
List<Employe> listEmploye = ids.stream()
   .map(Long::valueOf)
   .map(BigDecimal::valueOf)
   .map(this::findByIdPointage)
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use streams for this task, but you could improve your `for` loop if you want:

```
List<Employe> listEmploye = new ArrayList<>();
ids.forEach(id -> listEmploye.add(findByIdPointage(new BigDecimal(id))));
```